# Magento 2.2.1 Account Creation Error

Tags: login, customer-account, magento-2.2.1, create

When a user clicks 'Create and Account' from the top links, it successfully renders the account creation page.  However, when filling out the details (i.e. 'First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name', Newsletter Checkbox, 'Email', 'Password', and 'Confirm Password').

When clicking the 'Create An Account' button, the following error appears: "Something is wrong".

I have reviewed all of the logs that I can find and cannot find anything indicative to a problem.  I have also confirmed that the email address is not already within the database.  I have also successfully created an account post checkout as guest.

Magento version: 2.2.1

Comment: You can see exact error by echo error message from controller.

Comment: I do not see a controller for module-authorization.

Comment: I did see where the code is within Customer Controller Account, but I still do not see this error text.  It must be derived from an overridden class or referenced in some other way, globals???

Comment: Solved: I found that Google Invisible Captcha was inadvertently enabled.  Thank you!